# The relation $\sim$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $m\sim n$ if the HCF of $m$ and $n$ is $3$.

Tags: relations

a)Show that $\sim$ is neither reflexive or transitive.

b)Show that $\sim$ is symmetric.

If the HCF of $m$ and $n$ is 3, then the HCF of $n$ and $m$ is also $3$.

I think that my answer to b) is correct but I don't understand a). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You should look for counter examples for (a).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for (b) does seem correct, as you said.

Reflexive means that every element is related to itself. In particular, we would have needed to show $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n$~$n$. This is clearly not true. The HCF of any number with itself is the absolute value of itself: so the HCF of $n$ and $n$ is of course just $|n|$. There are many cases for which $|n| \neq 3$, hence this relation is not reflexive.

Transitive means that if I have $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $x$~$y$, and $y$~$z$, then $x$~$z$. Suppose that $x = z = 6$ and that $y = 3$. Clearly in this example, $x$~$y$ since the HCF of $x$ and $y$ is 3 and same for $y$~$z$. But the HCF of $x$ and $z$ is 6, so $x$ is not related to $z$ by ~.